# Music note appended to newlines Python

Tags: python, file, encoding, character

Specifically I have exported a csv file from Google Adwords.

I read the file line by line and change the phone numbers.

Here is the literal script:

```
for line in open('ads.csv', 'r'):
    newdata = changeNums(line)
    sys.stdout.write(newdata)
```

And `changeNums()` just performs some string replaces and returns the string.

The problem is at the end of the printed newlines is a musical note.

[image: musical note]

The original CSV does not have this note at the end of lines.  Also, I cannot copy-paste the note.

Is this some kind of encoding issue or what's going on?

Comment: That's probably just your text editor...

Comment: That screen is the IDLE output

Comment: Please include the output of `print repr(newdata)` result for such a line.

Comment: etc,etc`tAll\tActive\tActive\tActive\tApproved\r\n'` could it be because I'm on linux?

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but there is a csv module in the python standard library for csv files.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening with [universal line support](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

```
for line in open('ads.csv', 'rU'):
    # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- the original file has some characters on it (and they're being show as this symbol in the terminal)
- changeNums is creating those characters
- stdout.write is sending some non interpreted newline symbol, that again is being shown by the terminal as this symbol, change this line to a print(newdata)

My guess: changeNums is adding it.

Best debugging commands:

```
print([ord(x) for x in line])
print([ord(x) for x in newdata])
print line == newdata
```

And check for the character values present in the string.

Comment: changeNums() is literally `line = line.replace('123-456-7890', '098-555-5555')` a few times `return line`

Comment: It's '\r'. Change sys.std.write to print

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the newlines by:

```
for line in open('ads.csv', 'r'):
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    newdata = changeNums(line)
    sys.stdout.write(newdata)
```

An odd "note" character at the end is usually a CR/LF newline issue between *nix and *dos/*win environments.