# Python clear line weird note character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to create text that clears the previous line and then prints out a new one with different text. I have found a function, but instead of clearing the last line, it prints out a new one, but with a weird half note symbol.

```
from time import sleep
for x in range(10):
    print ('{0}\r'.format(x)),
    sleep(0.5)
```

It returns this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But each number has a half note next to it. (I can't display it on HTML)

I am using Python 3.5 on Raspbian Stretch on my RPi 3 if that helps.

**EDIT:** I have done some more investigating and found out that the problem is Unicode related.

Comment: Not all consoles use carriage return (`\r`) to return to the beginning of the current line. You might have a better luck with a backspace character (`\b`). Also, `print()` will automatically add a new line. Add `end=""` to its arguments (i.e. `print('{0}\r'.format(x), end="")`), to avoid that.

Comment: @zwer Or, more simply, `print(x, end='\r')`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708961/music-note-appended-to-newlines-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
for x in range(10):
    print (x,end='\r')
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Just tested in python 3.5.2-  doesn't work. You need to remove the comma after the print

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Removed it

Comment: The question specifies python-3.x, so this answer is perfectly correct, but for future viewers- in python-2.x print is still a statement so it doesn't have arguments line `end`, so you'll either need `from __future__ import print_function` or end the print statement in a `,` to prevent adding a newline.

Comment: It still creates the same error, except there aren't any new lines